# Realm relationships

Tags: android, realm

How to organize the import into the database without duplication. First, I created a table Stop. After I create a table Route, where one of the fields is a list of stops. My embodiments:

**1. Record in RealmList  id this Stop**

```
1.  realm.beginTransaction();
2.  Route route = realm.createObject(Route.class);
3.  route.setName("Route A");
4.  route.getStops().add(0);
5.  route.getStops().add(1);
6.  route.getStops().add(5);
7.  realm.commitTransaction();
```

**2. Acquire from BD object Stop by id, and written in RealmList**

```
1.  realm.beginTransaction();
2.  Route route = realm.createObject(Route.class);
3.  route.setName("Route A");
4.  for(Long id : stopsId) {
5.  Stop stop = realm.where(Stop.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
6.  if(stop!=null) route.getStops().add(stop); }
7.  realm.commitTransaction();
```

**Scheme** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCdCQ.jpg)

Comment: I don't really understand what is the problem here, since you answer the question yourself in point 2.
    ```Stop stop = realm.where(Stop.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    if(stop!=null) route.getStops().add(stop); }```

Comment: is the code actually working or not? what's the problem then?